# c++ constructor question

Tags: c++, constructor, default-parameters

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFont>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QWidget>

class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
    MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
};

MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    setFixedSize(200, 120);

    QPushButton *quit = new QPushButton(tr("Quit"), this);
    quit->setGeometry(62, 40, 75, 30);
    quit->setFont(QFont("Times", 18, QFont::Bold));

    connect(quit, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyWidget widget;
    widget.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

For this line :  `MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);`
why we need to put  `= 0` here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called an [Default parameter](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/CPLUSPLUS/CONCEPT/fundefault.html)

Basically you are saying unless you pass another value, the function (or constructor in this case) will be called with parent as 0.

When you'd had `MyWidget(QWidget *parent);` as constructor, you'd had to call it like `MyWidget widget(0);`

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to put zero there. C++ allows you to put default value for a parameter. In this case, parameter `parent` will default to 0 if the constructor is invoked without specifying an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to put it there, but it's a default value. If you don't pass any value to the constructor, it will take the '0' as value. It's making things a bit easier in some cases for the programmer.